# prosilica camera configuration

Tags: ros, face-detection, image-proc, prosilica-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if anybody knows a way/tool/wizard to find optimal configuration for Prosilica GC1380 camera. I use "AVT GigE SDK" and play with Exposure and Gain variables to get acceptable image at resolution 640x480, but the result fps is too low (less than 5). High fps comes with dark image. any suggestion to get image with quality and stream speed good enough for face_detector.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9522/prosilica-camera-configuration/) by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/126/reza/) on 2011-03-23**:
connected to my PC through ethernet connection. have access to aperture of the lens. my colleagues and I have tried various setting, but am not happy with trial and error method and looking for a procedure to produce best setting. it's necessary especially when light condition varying during day.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-22**:
How do you connect to this camera? Is it a direct connection? Have you access to the aperture of the lens itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try with a combination of [image_view](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view) and [dynamic reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) after starting your [camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/prosilica_camera).

```
roslaunch prosilica.launch #start your camera
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui  #start your GUI
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0